# Base case for not going out of the list?

Tags: haskell

Im very new to haskell and would like to know if theres a basic case for not going out of the list when going threw it!

For example in this code im trying to make a list where it compares the number on the right, and it if its bigger it stays on the list, otherwise we remove it, but it keeps giving me Prelude.head:empty list, since its comparing to nothing in the end im assuming. I've tried every base case i could think off... can anyone help me?

```
maiores:: [Int]->[Int]
maiores [] = []
maiores (x:xs) | x > (head xs) = [x] ++ [maiores xs)
               | otherwise = maiores xs
```

Comment: Ah, I misread your question at first.  It looks like you do understand the problem.  The trick to solving this is that it's ok to have *two* base cases.

Answer (score 2):

If your function is passed a list with one element, it will match `(x:xs)`, with `xs` matching `[]`. Then you end up with `head []` and thus your error. To avoid this, add an additional base case `maiores (x:[]) = ...` between your two existing cases, and fill it in appropriately.

Also: you can write `[x] ++ maiores xs` as `x : maiores xs`, which is more natural because you deconstruct a `:` and then immediately reconstruct it with the modified value, as opposed to indirectly using `++`.

Comment: Thank you for the answear! I have already tried dat base case actualy! And trying it again i made it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `head` or `tail` in your code, unless you can't avoid it. These are partial functions, which will crash when their input is empty.

Instead, prefer pattern matching: instead of

```
foo [] = 4
foo (x:xs) = x + head xs + foo (tail xs)
```

write

```
foo [] = 4
foo (x1:x2:xs) = x1 + x2 + foo xs
```

Now, if we turn on warnings with `-Wall`, GHC will suggest that the match in not exhaustive: we forgot to handle the `[_]` case. So, we can fix the program accordingly

```
foo [] = 4
foo [x] = x
foo (x1:x2:xs) = x1 + x2 + foo xs
```

Comment: Yes, this is the more idiomatic way to write this, over garunteeing a non-empty list is passed to `head`.

Comment: Im realy trying not to use commands in haskell since i gota write this myself in sheet later on. But than you for the answear anyways! One thing dat i did not understand is the foo[] = 4?

Answer (score 1):

Just make pattern matching more specific. Since (:) is right associative:

```
maiores:: [Int]->[Int]
maiores [] = []
maiores (x : y : xs) | x > y = [x] ++ maiores (y:xs)
maiores (_ : xs) = maiores xs
```

Comment: So technicly what you have done is, if theres a number dat we can compare with, the program choses  maiores (x:y:xs) and if it dosent it goes for maiores(_ : xs) ? But what if x is samller than y ? Does the program chose maiores(_ : xs) ?

Comment: @JoãoFerreira Patterns are tried in order. If there is only a single element in the list, the first and second pattern fail, and the third is taken (with `xs=[]`). If there are >=2 elements, the first pattern fails; the second pattern matches, but then `x>y` is checked. If it is true, the pattern succeeds, otherwise the pattern fails and the third one is tried. (So, yes, the program chooses `maiores (_:xs)` when x is smaller than y)